# Prove every non-zero subspace has a complement.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have a proof here, but have no idea where to begin.

> Let $V$ be a ﬁnitely dimensional vector space and $W$ a non-zero subspace of $V, W \neq V$. A complement to $W$ in $V$ is a subspace $U$ such that
>   $W ∩ U = {0_V} $ and $U + W = V$ . Prove that every non-zero subspace $W \neq V$
>   has a complement.

Honestly, I am having trouble even comprehending what a complement even is. Could someone provide a little guidance for a Linear Algebra noob?

Comment: A complement is what is lacking to get all the vectors in "something bigger" (in this case vector space $V$). Something and it's complement together build the whole.

Comment: A hint could be to start with a vector that's in $V$ but not in $W$. You can convince yourself that there must be such vectors. What can we do with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Begin by constructing a basis for $W$, {$x_1,...,x_j $} where for each $w \in W $ we have $w = a_1 x_1 + ... + a_j x_j $.

We can always extend this basis of $W $ to a basis for $V $ by finding vectors {$x_{j+1}, ... ,x_n $} such that for each vector $z \in V  \implies z=a_1x_1 + ... +a_j x_j + a_{j+1} x_{j+1} + ... + a_n x_n $

We do this by finding the first vector $x_{j+1} $ not in $W $ then taking all linear combinations of it with all of $W $. If this spans $V $, we are done, else grab the second vector not linearly dependent on the others.

Repeat until you have the basis for $V $ {$x_1,...,x_j,x_{j+1},...x_n $}.

Then the vectors {$x_{j+1},...,x_n$} define a subspace of $V $, call it $N $.

Now you prove this subspace $N $ is a direct sum with $W $.